# JavaScript array/object of functions by reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, pass-by-reference

Given:

```
function shout(){ alert('Hello!'); }
var dasarray = [ shout ];

shout();
dasarray[0]();

shout = function(){ alert('World!'); }

shout();
dasarray[0]();
```

Output:

```
Hello!

Hello!

World!

Hello!
```

I would've expected that `dasarray` received a reference to the function `shout`, but sadly the fourth output is also *hello*. If I assume right, I was able to modify the `shout` function correctly, but this leads to my assumption that the function was not passed by reference into `dasarray`.

Instead of an array I already tried this example with an object:

```
dasarray = { myfunction: shout }
```

With the same, disappointing, result.

My intention is to have an array/object of/with functions that are run in order and that can be extended in real time.

For example, extending the JavaScript code with new functionality and adding additional function calls to existing events that run in the correct order.

So, how can I put functions by reference into arrays/objects?

---

Thanks for the good answers. I just wanted to explain that I chose [Eli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438580/javascript-array-object-of-functions-by-reference/15438703#15438703), because it lead me to this setup:

```
zzz = {
    calls: [],
    shout: function(message) {
        alert('Shouting: ' + message);
    },
    initialize: function () {
        zzz.calls.push(['shout','Hello World']);
        zzz.calls.push(['shout','this is']);
        zzz.calls.push(['shout','my last shout!']);
        zzz.run();

        zzz.shout = function(){ alert('modified!'); };
        zzz.run();
    },
    run: function () {
        $.each(zzz.calls, function(){ zzz[this[0]](this[1]); }); // <- Using jQuery $.each here, just to keep it easy
    }
};

zzz.initialize();
```

Comment: It is a reference to the function. You're changing what `shout` is pointing at, the array still references the same function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [T.J.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438580/javascript-array-object-of-functions-by-reference/15438619#15438619).  However, if you wanted to do some kind of workaround, you could create a function that always does a "just in time" lookup from a cache of functions.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvZ98/)

```
var getFunctionRef = function(funcName)
{
    return function() { global[funcName](); };
}

var global = { };
var arr = [];

global.shout = function() { alert('hello'); }

arr[0] = getFunctionRef('shout');

global.shout = function() { alert('world'); }

arr[0]();
```

It's a very basic example.  There are more extensive ways of doing it.  But this should demonstrate the concept.

Comment: Thank you Eli, T. J. explained in a very good way, why this is not really that much of a reference than passing by value, but your solution also pushed me in the right direction to solve my problem!

Answer (score 7):

> I would've expected that dasarray received a reference to the function `shout`

It does. It does *not* receive a reference to the *variable* `shout`. (The symbol defined by the name of a function in a function declaration is, for virtually all intents and purposes, a variable — which is why you can assign to it later.) So your later line *changing* that variable:

```
shout = function(){ alert('World!'); }
```

...has no effect on the reference to the earlier function in `dasarray`.

Think of object references as a value saying where to find an object. When you do:

```
function shout(){ alert('Hello!'); }
```

...the symbol `shout` receives a *value* saying where that function is found, like this:

[image: Variable shout pointing to function object]

Then when you do:

```
var dasarray = [ shout ];
```

...that *value* is put in the first entry in the array. Now the symbol `shout` and the first entry in `dasarray` both have the same value, which tells the JavaScript engine where to find that function object in memory. So we have this:

[image: Variable shout and dasarray entry 0 pointing to same function object]

But the variable `shout` and the entry in `dasarray` have no connection whatsoever to each other.

Then you do this:

```
shout = function(){ alert('World!'); }
```

...that creates a new function and stores a new value in the variable `shout` saying where that new function is. But that has no effect on the value stored in `dasarray`'s entry `0`. We end up with this:

[image: Var shout pointing to second function, dasarray entry 0 pointing to first function]

I'm saying "value" a lot above because that's what an "object reference" is: A value, just like the value `5`. It's just that the way that value is used is to *look up* where an object is. When you assign that value from one variable to another, the value gets copied, just like the value `5` gets copied when you copy it from one variable to another.

I can't say I like [Eli's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438580/javascript-array-object-of-functions-by-reference/15438703#15438703) much, I'd rather just be much more direct about it and use objects in the simple way:

```
var obj = {
    shout: function() { alert("Hello!"); }
};
var dasarray = [ obj ];

obj.shout();                               // Hello!
dasarray[0].shout();                       // Hello!

obj.shout = function() { alert("World"); };

obj.shout();                               // World!
dasarray[0].shout();                       // World!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that made it clear, but @EliGassert also provided a very nice workaround :)

Comment: @FTav: Glad that helped. Due respect to Eli, but I think there's a better way to do it. That's more complex than necessary. FWIW, I've given a more direct way above.

Comment: No qualms about your solution.  It's clean (especially the new edits).  +1 to your answer.  My solution was very generic and doesn't serve a real-world scenario.  I imagine another layer or two of abstraction, separating the dasarray from the caller.  Otherwise, you could even get more direct and change `global` to `dasarray` and modify the functions directly in the array.  But I imagine the real solution will be more complicated than the example given and solutions we've presented.